# Changing Variable values in Tensorflow and evaluating the cost function

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

I need to be able to plot e.g. the cost function values as a function of some parameter (for example the bias `b` below). If e.g. my graph is something like (pseudocode)

```
y = g(W x + b),
cost = sum(y ** 2),
```

where `W` and `b` are `tf.Variables`, I'd like to change `b` from, say 0 to 1 and plot the values of `cost`.

**Please note that I do not want to call eval or sesssion.run after each change of `b` because of the overhead!** E.g. for 100 plot points that would take forever.

- I know of the existence of `tf.assign`, but doing something like [assign, cost, assign, cost, ...] and evaluating that doesn't seem to work
- I guess I could update the value of `b` inside the graph and call cost after each update, but I wouldn't really want to change the graph

So how could I do this in an efficient manner? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: actually this is probably impossible to do without calling eval/run between the iterations... oh well...

Comment: Basically you want to update each W and b in each iteration ?

Comment: Sorry, I was not being specific enough: in this example, I would want to update the values of `b` only, but of course that would apply to `W` as well.

Comment: ok you want to update b w.r.t it's  gradients . And you want to calculate gradients by yourself or by using some tf.gradients() where it will auto differentiate the function

Comment: No I don't want to compute any gradients. I just want to get the cost value with some input data, then change the value of `b`by hand, then get cost value, then change etc.

Answer (score 1):

In tensor-flow if you use variables you can only evaluate them only after an initialization. So you cannot probably evaluate them without a session.
but you can change the parameters like the following way

```
import tensorflow as tf 
my_var = tf.Variable(10)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(my_var.initializer)
    print(sess.run(my_var.assign_sub(2)))   #>> 8
    print(sess.run(my_var.assign_sub(2)))   #>> 6
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, I know how to use assign, but unfortunately I can't work with sess.run or eval since the overhead for doing so is too high (I have a biiig model). Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for **feeding** a different value at each step. Assuming `b` is a scalar variable, you could code your loop with something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

# Vary `b_val` from 0 to 1 in 100 steps.
for b_val in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):

  # Evaluate `cost` using `b = b_val`.
  cost_val = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={b: b_val})

  # Do something with `cost_val`....
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that... unfortunately the overhead for calling Session.run or eval is way too high (I have a big model), so that just doesn't work for me. That's why I write the stuff in the first bullet point about the possibility of defining something like `my_list = [assign, cost, assign, cost, ...]` and then doing `sess.run(my_list)`, instead of doing a loop of `sess.run`s. Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: If the amount of work per bias value is truly very small (on the order of tens of microseconds or less), the only remaining option would be to move the calculation into something like  `biases = np.linspace(...); costs = tf.map_fn(bias_values, lambda b: tf.reduce_sum(...))`, where the whole expression for calculating the cost is moved into the `lambda` expression. Would that work?

Comment: hmm that could work... I'll give it a try asap and will let you know, thanks!